# Why is Typescript calling an overridden child method from within the parent class if I call child.listen()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, this

```
class Base {

    setupServer(){
        console.log("BaseClass")
    }

    listen() {
        this.setupServer();
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

    setupServer() {
        console.log("ChildClass")
    }
}

const child = new Child();
child.listen();
```

Why does this print out: `ChildClass`? I would expect `this` in the `Base` class to only see the `setupServer` method in the same class. Is there a way to call the `listen` function from the child instance and then still execute the `Base` class `setupServer()` method first without doing a `super.setupServer()` in the Child class?

Comment: That’s how inheritance works. The current object (`this`) only has one method of that name, and in the child that’s the child version. `this` refers to the ***current object***, not the class.

Comment: You can invoke Base's setupServer method from Child via `super.setupServer()`, but as @deceze says, the behavior you're seeing is kind of the point of overriding methods.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but if I remove the `setupServer()` method from the Base class, the compiler complains due to `this.setupServer()` in the listen method. Is this because the compiler does not know that the child class contains the implementation?

Comment: @Loupi TS cannot let you do that, because then you will be able to create invalid objects from Base Class itself.

Comment: If you remove it from the base class, then there’s the possibility that you instantiate the base class, and then your code would break. It’s not *type safe* then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in a function depends on how it is executed. Here it is executed on child instance so child's `setupServer` method will be called.

Regarding the question as to why removing the `setupServer` from base class shows an error in TS:

```
class Base {

    listen() {
        this.setupServer();
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

    setupServer() {
        console.log("ChildClass")
    }
}

const child = new Child();
child.listen();
```

It is simple, in this case you can anytime create an object from Base Class and that will fail when you call `this.listen()`. Typescript cannot let you do that even if `setupServer` function is defined later in child class.

Answer (score 0):

Even when you subclass another class: an instance is just one `this` object even when a method on the base class gets to do something with it.

So in your example, when the `listen` method on the `Base` class invokes `this.setupServer()`, that `this` is still `child`, which is an instance of `Child`, and the hierarchical lookup  of `setupServer` will therefore match the one defined on `Child`.